# Как выполнить код в Live Wallpaper

Tags: java, android

Нашёл простой пример как [ставить живые обои в формате GIF на экран](http://learn-android.ru/news/delaem_zhivye_oboi_s_gif_animacii/2015-03-03-59)

Воспроизвёл, [работает](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kpJ1Y-pcMET0w1Yko1LWRnbFk/view?usp=sharing).

Как модифицировать этот код, чтобы вместо *GIF* можно было подставлять своё *активити*?

Comment: активити как живые обои выставить нельзя.

Comment: ОК. 
Тогда как какой нибудь свой java код вставить? Например ParticleSystemDemo  https://github.com/kozhin2012/bayninestudios/tree/master/ParticleSystemDemo

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20live%20wallpaper%20sample&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

По вашей ссылке в примере за отрисовку живых обоев отвечает класс

```
private class GIFWallpaperEngine extends WallpaperService.Engine {

    private void draw() {
      if (visible) {
         Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
         canvas.save();
         //Регулируем масштаб и положение на экране нашей анимации
         canvas.scale(3f, 3f);
         movie.draw(canvas, -100, 0);
         canvas.restore();
         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
         movie.setTime((int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % movie.duration()));

         handler.removeCallbacks(drawGIF);
         handler.postDelayed(drawGIF, frameDuration);
      }
    }
}
```

Здесь в методе `draw()` переопределяйте отрисовку как вам угодно.